# .net: Should our custom Data Access Layer classes implement Idisposable?

Tags: .net, data-access-layer, idisposable

.net: Should our custom Data Access Layer classes implement Idisposable? They use mainly a Database as a Data Store for storing/retrieving data?

Thank you

Comment: **Do they encapsulate and therefore have a need to dispose objects that themselves implement `IDisposable`?** If so, then yes. Otherwise, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dispose is primary used to free unmanaged resources. For instance sockets, connections to databases and file handles.

If you do not keep track of any unmanaged resources yourself you do not **need** to implement `IDisposable` since all resources are freed when the `DbConnection` is collected by the GC.

I would recommend you to do two things:

a) If you have a DbConnection as a member variable, implement `IDisposable` and dispose the connection in the Dispose method. This will only work if you are using the `using` keyword when using your DAL.

b) Start using `using` anywhere you can to make sure that resources are freed as soon as possible.

Comment: It is dangerous to assume that any type of IDisposable object will be safely and adequately cleaned up by the GC unless you have explicit documentation promising that.  For a class which subscribes to events from long-lived objects to clean up after itself when abandoned, it must generally either route all events through two extra layers of indirection, or all non-event operations through at least one.  While some event-subscribing database wrappers may do that, I wouldn't rely upon all of them to do so.

Comment: Actually, the event thingy you talk about is not just for IDisposable but for all objects that are going to be garbage collected. The OP did not ask about if it's safe to not call Dispose but if he need to implement IDisposable.